# How to enable horizontal overflow in vertically scrollable parent?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I built a CSS structure using TailwindCSS to describe the issue I'm currently encountering. I chose Tailwind Playground to build the layout quickly but you can share your solution idea in plain CSS, doesn't matter at all.

Here is the code and output: https://play.tailwindcss.com/8xynVWIRC7

And the structure for those who can't visit the link:

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-0 h-screen w-screen overflow-hidden">
  <div class="h-screen col-span-1 bg-gray-300 p-6 space-y-6 overflow-y-scroll overflow-x-visible">
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 hover:w-96 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-span-2 bg-gray-100"></div>
  <div class="h-screen col-span-1 bg-gray-300 p-6 space-y-6 overflow-y-scroll overflow-x-visible">
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 w-96 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
    <div class="h-36 bg-gray-400 rounded-lg drop-shadow-md"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, let me explain the problem:

[image: please see this image]

If you take a look at the image above, I have sidebars on both left-hand and right-hand side, and a content area in the middle. Both sidebars should be vertically scrollable since they contain enough content to overflow the screen height.

Problem #1: I want the contents inside of these sidebars can overflow horizontally outside of the sidebars when needed. (I need to see they overflow especially on hover states) But as you can see in the screen shot, they don't overflow their parent element (sidebar). However, if I remove the class ("overflow-y-scroll") I added to enable vertical scroll in sidebars, they can overflow. But in this case, I sacrifice the scroll feature. How can I make them overflow maintaining vertical scroll?

Problem #2: The contents in the right-hand side sidebar try to overflow to the right. However, they should overflow towards the main content area (I mean, to the left). How can I do it? I've read about "direction: rtl;" but it changes the direction of child elements, so it doesn't work for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, I've never used tailwinds, but I may help with CSS,
Did you try to add overflow-x: auto; also for the main parent (sidebar) you could just add padding (right and left) to let the content go automatically towards the center.